# Getting started with Android Development basics

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Is there a good tutorial on the net somewhere that delineates the steps needed to get started programming an Android application from square one on windows 7?  I am looking to basically hit a Web Service and display it on a phone as a view of sorts (Kind of using the MVC design pattern).   I have downloaded eclipse and I have downloaded the Android SDK.  But I think I am missing some things.  In addition, do you think it is easier to develop Android apps on Linux or Windows?  I developed in java during college, and I just thought it was easier doing it on Java then on windows.  Let me know what you think.

Comment: Have you done a basic web search looking for Android Tutorials or something similar?

Comment: Also, since this question can't really have a single correct answer and is soliciting "what's best" sort of opinions, it isn't really a good fit for the SO format.

Comment: Disagree about unsuitability.  Despite the official SO format, it's also become a repository for a lot of "how to get started", "list of best books for X", that sort of thing.  Question can easily be reworded to "what's the best tutorial available".

Comment: Please look at the [android tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/android/info) for resources on getting started in Android development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't post a comment so I will have to write a answer to your question, although I doubt this is a typical answer as well as a typical question for StackOverflow.

I've read a lot on Android before starting programming for it, I can hint you on what resources I found the best to make your way into Android development.

Concerning books I found these to be the best when starting:

- [Android Recipes: A Problem-Solution Approach](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Android-Recipes-Problem-Solution-Jeff-Friesen/dp/143023413X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1327413272&sr=8-1)
- [Beginning Android 2](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Beginning-Android-2-Mark-Murphy/dp/1430226293/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1327413381&sr=1-1)

  More recently to deal with more advanced topics [I've found The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development](http://commonsware.com/Android/) to be a really helpful resource.

You also have some really helpful resources online, specially the android development website. Start from the [DevGuide](http://developer.android.com/guide/basics/what-is-android.html) and it will give you a clear big picture on the subject. The other section of the android dev website that you can take advantage of is the [tutorial section](http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=tutorial). I would recommend you to the these, specially the first ones as they are very basic.

I'm assuming that you have a basic understanding of Java by not referencing you any Java learning resources.